# jQuery: Detect duplicate in select & show an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below has a select with three options.  When you choose one of the options and click add the option is added to the table. If the user were try to choose the same option I need an alert or modal window to appear saying "Duplicates not allowed."

Anyone have an idea how to accomplish that?

```js
 $("select#keys").change(function(){

     $("#add-user-code").click(function(){
   var selectedKey = $("#keys").val();
   $("#3rd-row").show();
    $('#example').html('<span class="lbl">' + selectedKey + '&nbsp;</span>');   
     });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<select class="select-duc" id="keys">
        <option></option>          
        <option>Allergies</option>
        <option>Animals</option>
      <option>Coughing</option> 
 </select>
 
<button type="button" id="add-user-code" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Add User Code</button>
      
 
  <div class="col-sm-6 reset">
    <div class="details-page-container two">
 <h5>User Codes</h5>
 <div class="table-container">
  <table>
 <tbody><tr>
 <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Domain</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Start Date</strong></th>
 <th><strong>End Date</strong></th>
 <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>01</td>
 <td>MINNEAPOLIS</td>
 <td>MN</td>
 <td>11/01/2019</td>
 <td></td>
 <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>02</td>
 <td>MINNEAPOLIS</td>
 <td>MN</td>
 <td>11/01/2019</td>
 <td></td>
 <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
  <tr id="3rd-row" class="hideIT">
 <td id="example"></td>
 <td>MINNEAPOLIS</td>
 <td>MN</td>
 <td>11/01/2019</td>
 <td>12/01/2019</td>
 <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" href="#">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an array, and
In your $("#add-user-code").click function:
Check if the value(which user selected) is already present in the array or not(To show the alert),
push the index/value to the array after adding it to your table(So that next time the condition fails and alert would show up).

Also, don't forget to remove items from the array whenever needed(User Starts again or item is removed from the table)/

Answer (score 0):

I'd better just hide the duplicate option when the one is selected and show them back when/if its unselected, for better user experience.
Otherwise, you can make an array of selected values and loop through it when an option selected, something like this:

```
     var selectedOptions = [];
     $("select#keys").change(function(){

     $("#add-user-code").click(function(){
     var selectedKey = $("#keys").val();
     if($.inArray(selectedKey, selectedOptions)) {
        alert ("Duplicate values are not allowed");
      } else {
         selectedOptions.push(selectedKey);
      }
      $("#3rd-row").show();
      $('#example').html('<span class="lbl">' + selectedKey + '&nbsp;</span>');   
      });  
});
```

Still, it has to be reset when options are unselected, I don't see multiple options in your snippet, though

Comment: Thanks and it almost works as seen at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wuyjzda9/ .  The user should be allowed to choose the first option without seeing the pop up.  When the user chooses a 2nd time and they choose the same option as the first then the alert pop up should appear.  Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return all the values to check whether the value the user wants to insert does not exits already

```js
function getTableValues() {
   return $('tr').find('td:first-child').map(function() {
      return $( this ).text();
   }).get();
  }
  
   $("select#keys").change(function(){

      $("#add-user-code").click(function(){
    var selectedKey = $("#keys").val();
    if(!getTableValues().includes(selectedKey)) {
     $("#3rd-row").show();
      $('#example').html('<span class="lbl">' + selectedKey + '&nbsp;</span>');   
     }
     else {
      alert('Duplicate not allowed');
     }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `.click()` bind inside of the `.change()` bind. Also, rather than using an alert, you could just make that option not available.

```
$("#add-user-code").click(function(){
  $('#example').html('<span class="lbl">' + $('#keys option:selected').hide().text() + '&nbsp;</span>');
  $("#3rd-row").show();
  $('#keys option:eq(0)').prop('selected', 'selected'); //set the select back to the blank option
});
```

Then if you click delete:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  let example = $('#example .lbl').text().trim();
  $('#keys option').filter(function() {return this.textContent === example; }).show();
  $("#3rd-row").hide();
});
```

You shouldn't need an array or function to achieve what you're after.
https://jsfiddle.net/g9523ysz/

If you really need an alert:

```
$("#add-user-code").click(function(){
  let option = $('#keys option:selected').text();

  if (option) {
    if ($('td').filter(function() { return $(this).find('.lbl').text().trim() === option; }).length){
      alert('Duplicates not allowed.');
    } else {
      $("#3rd-row").show();
      $('#example').html('<span class="lbl">' + option + '&nbsp;</span>');
    }
  }
});
```

I would suggest that if you can, use a more specific class for the span, like `lbl-user-code`. Then rather than having to check every single `td` you could:

```
if ($('.lbl-user-code').filter(function() { return this.textContent === option; }).length) { ... }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9us4d08j/

Comment: Thanks, but i need an alert.  This is for application written years ago.

Comment: Edited to answer your actual question. However, in my opinion, it's a much better user experience just not being able to select an option rather than selecting an option and then being told nope, just kidding, you can't select that option.